# How to receive access granted this python code?

Tags: python

I have this piece of code in python:

```
password = "1234"

user_pwd = input("Please type your password: ")
print(user_pwd)
if  password == user_pwd:
    print("Access granted")
else:
    print("Access denied")
```

Is there anyway to "SQL injection" this code, so that we can receive `Access granted` without typing in the correct password.

Comment: No, this completely checks it. Python is a lot more thorough than sql.

Comment: The short answer, "no". The long answer, "not yet". If you find a way be sure to let people know.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama Honestly it's not SQL but people who abuse it by doing funny things like concatenating strings to write dynamic SQL. You should never execute what a user types in. Just have a look at (many) Stack Overflow answers that recommend using `eval()` to create the same vulnerabilities in Python.

Comment: thanks to you all for your helpful response

Comment: please give me an upvote